# Ruby class method scope. Why method is private?

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, oop, methods

The main point of my short app was to find prices that consists of seven digits (greater than a million) from user's input.

I wrote this:

```
class Price
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(str)
    @data = str
  end

  def lookup
    @data.select do |i|
      i[/\d{1,7}+/]
    end
  end

  def print_and_max
    puts "Here comes the maximum"
    # some code and voila
  end

end

prices = gets.to_a
str = Price.new(prices)
print str.lookup
```

I get this error:

```
price.rb:21:in `<main>': undefined method `to_a' for "124789358124 12478912578915 50000000 50204500\n":String (NoMethodError)
```

OK, let's try again:

```
class Price
  attr_accessor :data

  prices = []

  def initialize(str)
    @data = str
  end

  def lookup
    @data.select do |i|
      i[/\d{1,7}+/]
    end
  end

  def print_and_max
    puts "Here comes the maximum"
    # some code and voila
  end

end

prices = gets
str = Price.new(prices)
print str.lookup
```

And then result is like that:

```
price.rb:11:in `lookup': private method `select' called for "124789358124 12478912578915 50000000 50204500":String (NoMethodError)
```

Seems that I completely don't understand method scope in Ruby. The main idea is to grab the string of numbers separated by spaces or something else, then convert it to array and print it. Writing method that will put out max value is optional. Why select method is private? I've tried to relate my Price class to Array as a child but select method remained private.

I've tried this:

```
prices = [125215213]
```

@data is accessible:

```
irb(main):028:0* str.data
=> [125215213]
```

.lookup is not:

```
irb(main):029:0> str.lookup
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into Integer
    from (irb):11:in `[]'
    from (irb):11:in `block in lookup'
    from (irb):10:in `select'
    from (irb):10:in `lookup'
    from (irb):29
    from /Users/shu/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):030:0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your main problem is that you're trying to treat a String as if it were an Array.

Comment: It sounds like what you need help with is interpreting error messages correctly. Your guesses are not quite on the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user input looks like this:
"124789358124 12478912578915 50000000 50204500"

Then you can turn that into an array like this:

```
prices = gets.split
```

split is a String class method that splits chunks of text into array elements.  By default it splits on whitespace, but you can pass it an argument if you're not splitting on whitespaces (looks like you are).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
price = gets
```

to this:

```
price = gets.chomp.split(" ")
```

That will split the string into an array, separating it at every " " it finds. And chomp, will remove the newline that will be added after the user enters their input.